# Unity WebGL Build crashs when Change Scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash, webgl

I made a webgl application in Unity and first had problems with a red warning on the screen when uploading to Github.
I solved this problem in forums skill the Decompression Fallback option
However another severe error appeared. Every time I click on a button to change scene the page freezes until the browser warns that it crashes

How can I solve this error?
I will leave the settings I use here
It is a super simple 2D game that uses elements from Unity itself, I even tried to remove a plugin that I had

It's just a scene with a button, scene changes with

> public void ChangeScene(string sceneToGo){
> SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneToGo); }

When I click on another button for testing and it works. The problem is when it loads a new scene.

Prints:

[Player Settings 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUXZ3.png)

[Player Settings 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xSfc.png)

[Player Settings 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGhvM.png)

Comment: Without knowing what the errors are. What scenes you built into it it’s unanswerable

Comment: It's just a scene with a button, scene changes with SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneToGo);

Comment: Did you put the scenes in your build?

Comment: Yes, when I click on another button for testing and it works. The problem is when it loads a new scene